# Why do I get the error: Could not find import, when compiling on truffle

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, erc20

So, I'm trying to compile in truffle some open zeppelin ERC20 contracts, but I get the following error:

Error: Error: Could not find
import from any sources; imported from C:/Users/Angel/Documents/blockchain course/ethereum game/solidity/contracts/GameToken.sol
at Object.compile (C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\workflow-compile\legacy\index.js:72:1)

Token file:[image]

Migration file:
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the [documentation](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/), the correct imports are

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol";
```

Comment: When I switch the library from `openzeppelin-solidity` -> `@openzeppelin`, the only difference is the pat that the error complains about. Now getting `Could not find @openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20Detailed.sol from any sources`.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, asked the question on the openzeppelin forums and found a solution:

https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/could-not-find-import-from-any-sources-error/2656/5